# How to Import CSV in Redis

Tags: python, redis

Heres how to import CSV files into Redis db

Shoud do this and does it will be deleted tommorow
`

```
import redis
from csv import reader
import csv

# password='redispw' falls geschützt, port und host ändern wenn auf Linux läuft 
db = redis.Redis(host= 'localhost', port=49153, password='redispw')

with open('band.csv', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    # delimiter=',' wenn durch komma getrennt wenn durch Tab dann ='\t'
    bandreader = reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    #bandreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in bandreader:
        # Setzten des Keys was drinne stehen soll Bsp: id oder Name als key
        redisKey = row[1]
        # Was soll alles in der Value stehen ist so ne art zsmfassung mit 
        redisVal = "member: " + row[2] + ", group: " + row[3] + ", role: " + row[4] + ", start: " + row[5] + ", end:" + row[6]  
        print(f"rediskey = { redisKey }, redisVal = { redisVal }\n")
        # man kann auch set benutzen aber hier sadd und mit smembers kann abgefragt werden
        db.sadd(redisKey, redisVal)
```

`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is phrased incorrectly. You don't want to import a csv file in redis, you wish to set key value from a csv into your redis.

In this case, your design should be a bit different, to avoid decoupling, have a method that reads your csv and return a dictionary as you noted `row[1]` and `row[2]` is your value.

once you return your dictionary, you can iterate   it like this:

```
db = redis.Redis(host= 'localhost', port=49153, password='redispw')


for key,value in my_dict.items():
    db.set(key,value)
```